# Another round table problem involving 12 chairs and 5 persons

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I spent a couple of hours thinking about the following excercise:

Given a round table with 12 chairs, how many possibilites exist to place 5 persons at this chair. There should be at least one chair between each two persons. The chairs are not numbered and the possibilities only differing in the rotation of the table are equal.

I think there are the following three possible patterns of free chairs (0) and persons (1)

`1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0`

`0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1`

`0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1`

every other combination of persons and chairs could be shifted to one of these three.

So there is one last thing to do, the possibilities of the 5 persons sitting on 5 chairs, this leads to `5!`.

So my answer is:

$
3 * 5! = 360
$

There is a bonus task, I should give a generall solution für n chairs and k persons. It would be great to get some advice on this bonus task, because I got stuck thinking about this.

Edit:

The persons are distinguishable.

Comment: You should clarify if the 5 persons are indistinguishable (seem that way) or distinguished.

Comment: you can distinguish between persons

Answer (score 1):

Your method works, but here is an approach that will generalize better. (Everything I do here can be done for $k$ people sitting in $n$ chairs.)

Imagine each person sitting at the table rudely puts their feet on the chair to their left. This should always be possible if there's a gap between any two people. Conversely, if it is possible, then the gap is ensured.

So we can imagine that each person sitting at the table occupies *two* chairs in this way, and we are trying to arrange $5$ people and $2$ empty chairs around the circle.

To deal with rotations, the easiest thing to do is to fix the position of person 1. Then we are trying to arrange the remaining $4$ people and $2$ empty chairs in a sequence that can no longer be rotated, and this is easy: it's $\frac{6!}{2!} = 360$.

(There are $6$ people and empty chairs to rearrange in $6!$ ways, but we divide by the $2!$ ways to rearrange the empty chairs, which doesn't change the outcome.)